# How to use the Foursquare API to get Venue Details

Tags: php, api, foursquare

So I'm trying to get details of a specific venue using PHP. Here's my code that attempts to use a GET request to the Foursquare API to return results and then process them as JSON and display the name, address and city:

```
$curlhandle = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b522afaf964a5200b6d27e3");
            curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

            $response = curl_exec($curlhandle);
            curl_close($curlhandle);

            $json = json_decode($response);
            foreach ($json->groups[0]->venues as $result)
            {
                echo $result->name.' - '.$result->address.' '.$result->city."<p />";
            }
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm completely new to PHP and the Foursquare API so it could be something glaringly obvious.

Comment: It looks like the you need to authenticate before you can use the Foursquare API.

Comment: I thought this type of request didn't need authentication because it's nothing to do with a user, just publically available information? If I do need to authenticate how do I go about doing this?

Comment: You are right, you can call venues without authentication, but you need to add your client id and secret to the call to identify yourself to Foursquare

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to authenticate using the OAuth flow to get venue information, but you do need to add your Client ID and Client Secret to the API call.

So, the URL should be something like:

```
"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4b522afaf964a5200b6d27e3?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
```

Comment: Ah right thank you very much for the reply! How do I find out my client ID and secret? Also does the code for displaying the JSON look correct to you? I'm very inexperienced with this stuff as you can probably tell!

Comment: You can sign up for a client id and secret here: https://foursquare.com/oauth/

as for the json parsing I have no idea - not a PHP guy I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks a lot, still struggling with the JSON parsing and can't seem to make any head way which is extremely odd!

Comment: @Martin isn't that technically wrong, Client_id and client_secret are post fields, but here you are appending them as parameters on a URL

Comment: @OllieHind Hi i m also stuck here have u able to parse data.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the URL should be

```
`https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/${venue_id}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&client_secret=${CLIENT_SECRET}&v=20180323`
```

Note, I am using template literals and don't forget `v=20180323` because the Foursquare API no longer supports requests that do not pass in a version parameter. Of course, you can modify the version number to keep updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate your request, if you go to the URL you get this.

```
{"meta":{"code":400,"errorType":"invalid_auth","errorDetail":"Missing access credentials. See https:\/\/developer.foursquare.com\/docs\/oauth.html for details."},"response":{}}
```

So I'd say you need to authenticate by following this: https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth.html

Comment: Same here, but I don't understand, why. In the official developer page (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) it says: Requires Acting User: No, ergo a client id and a secret should be enough. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: (on Python)

```
    url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/{0}'.format(self.placeid)

    params = dict(
        client_id=self.clientid,
        client_secret=self.clientsecret,
        v='20170801'
    )
    r = requests.get(url=url, params=params)
```